# What is the solution for rejected applications

Tags: ionic-framework, payment

This is respon from Apple :

Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

We noticed that your app includes or accesses paid digital content, services, or functionality by means other than in-app purchase, which is not appropriate for the App Store. Specifically:

- The digital content can be purchased in the app using payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

Next Steps

The paid digital content, services, or subscriptions included in or accessed by your app must be available for purchase using in-app purchase.

If you have any additional information to provide regarding the digital content and services in your app and how the guidelines apply to them, please reply to this message in Resolution Center and let us know. If there is information you'd like us to consider in our review of future submissions, please feel free to include it in the App Review Information section of App Store Connect.

Resources

- See how to implement in-app purchase with the StoreKit framework.
- Review step-by-step instructions for creating in-app purchases in App Store Connect.
- Learn more about our policies for apps that offer paid digital content and services.

Do you have solution  ?

Comment: You must use (only) Apple's in-app purchase services.  Solution: remove the code in your app that uses other payment mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks ... is there no other solution? Payment Gateway https://midtrans.com/

Comment: Eka - nope.  No other solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apple Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) state this:

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase:
>
> [...] Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

As far as I am aware, there are no exceptions.

So the **ONLY** solution to your problem is to remove the code in your app that uses other payment mechanisms.